# VisualStudio RC 2017 Git integration

Tags: git, visual-studio-2017

I have a project that has one branch called 'deploy'.
While command line Git and SmartGit have no problems with it, VS2017 doesn't like it at all when I select it:

[image: VS2017 git integration error]

obviously, I can't change the command line since it's part of VisualStudio but I was wondering if something can be changed in the project to alleviate that problem (I can't change the branch's name since it's used in the tool chain)

Comment: What was the action you tried to execute. What does the Git Output window show?

Comment: There is nothing at all in the output window. If I switch branches (to deploy) and do sync, the message will appear; but if I switch to deploy without doing any other operations, in SmartGit, then the message will pop up in VS as well.

Comment: So you're able to switch branches... Are you able to Fetch? Are you able to Pull? Sync does a number of operations in sequence, narrowing down the problem may help.

Comment: What's the name of the remote you've used? The default `origin` or something else?

Comment: I can't do any operations on the deploy branch within VS; smartgit / cmd line works properly. The remote is the default "origin". There is nothing exotic about the repo. I should add a note that VS2015 handles the same repo without any problem.

Comment: VS2017 has a completely new Git interface, so new issues are possible. It looks like something in your repo is special about the word `deploy`, there may be one or more tag, branch, remote, ref or file with the name `deploy` and the git command generated by Visual Studio isn't specific enough in saying which.

Comment: Is the name `deploy` important locally? If not, try creating a local branch tracking the remote `origin/deploy` branch, but using a different local name.

Comment: yes, it is important since a few remote services depend on it and changing them would be more work that not using VS's git integration. I was hoping this problem had been seen before and there was a workaround, but it looks like I'll just wait for the next update! anyhow, thanks for spending time looking into it.

Answer (score 0):

If the name deploy is only important on the remote, then you could try using the "New local branch from" option and using a different name:

[image]

That gives you a remote branch with the right name and hopefully a local branch that works. The "Track remote" option ensures that your local branch is linked to the remote branch it was created from.

Since this is most likely a bug, I also suggest submitting it over at:

- https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/

Comment: It’s a good idea but all the tool chain relies on the names of 2 branches